# How to show server returned JSON on a client running google chart on a page in realtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am not a javascript developer not even expert in ajax, just a no vice desktop developer , I would really appreciate if you can show me how can I connect MCU returning json data to a web page that uses google gauge running on client on local network at home.

So I have implemented a simple Arduino based web sever that returns data in below format:

```
{“arduino”:
[ 
{“location”:”outdoor”,”temperature”:”15.55″},
{“location”:”outdoor”,”humidity”:”15″}
]
}
```

I want to be able to show live temperature without having to refresh the whole page: I came across with [google gauge example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples#gauge_example).

I have modified the example in the link below to display temperature and humidity separate gauge:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawGauge);
    var gaugeOptions = {min: 0, max: 280, yellowFrom: 200, yellowTo: 250,
      redFrom: 250, redTo: 280, minorTicks: 5};
    var gauge;

    function drawGauge() {
      gaugeData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      gaugeData.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
      gaugeData.addColumn('number', 'Humidity');
      gaugeData.addRows(2);
      gaugeData.setCell(0, 0, 120);
      gaugeData.setCell(0, 1, 80);

      gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div'));
      gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
    }

    function changeTemp(dir) {
      gaugeData.setValue(0, 0, gaugeData.getValue(0, 0) + dir * 25);
      gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
    }

    function changeHumid(dir) {
      gaugeData.setValue(0, 1, gaugeData.getValue(0, 1) + dir * 20);
      gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="gauge_div" style="width:280px; height: 140px;"></div>
  <small>Change</small>
  <input type="button" value="Temperature" onclick="changeTemp(1)" />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" value="Humidity" onclick="changeHumid(1)" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Now I want the change temperate and change Humidity functions should execute after 5 sec displaying latest data from the json returned by executing the MCU bee server URL ? How can I implement that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out, after lots of digging, I finally have something working before I finish my vacation.

below code works and displays the latest value in my google gauge and it refreshes after every 15 seconds, same principle I can apply on json data I have put as sample in the Opening post.

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

  // set your channel id here
  var channel_id = 166617;
  // set your channel's read api key here if necessary
  var api_key = 'ZCUB611J8M8ELM9M';
  // maximum value for the gauge
  var max_gauge_value = 70;
  // name of the gauge
  var gauge_name = 'Temperature';

  // global variables
  var chart, charts, data;

  var public_key = 'dZ4EVmE8yGCRGx5XRX1W';

  // load the google gauge visualization
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(initChart);

  // display the data
  function displayData(point) {
    data.setValue(0, 0, gauge_name);
    data.setValue(0, 1, point);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

  // load the data
  function loadData() {
    // variable for the data point
    var p;

     // JSONP request
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: 'https://data.sparkfun.com/output/' + public_key + '.json',
          data: {page: 1},
          dataType: 'jsonp',
        }).done(function (results){

      // get the data last value
      p = results[results.length - 1].tempf;

      // if there is a data point display it
      if (p) {
        displayData(p);
      }

    });
  }

  // initialize the chart
  function initChart() {

    data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addRows(1);

    chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div'));
    options = {width: 120, height: 120, greenFrom: 10, greenTo: 29, redFrom: 41, redTo: 70, yellowFrom:30, yellowTo: 40, minorTicks: 5};

    loadData();

    // load new data every 15 seconds
    setInterval('loadData()', 15000);
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y650ven5/) for you:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['gauge']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawGauge);
var gaugeOptions = {
  min: 0,
  max: 280,
  yellowFrom: 200,
  yellowTo: 250,
  redFrom: 250,
  redTo: 280,
  minorTicks: 5
};
var gauge;
var gaugeData;

function drawGauge() {
  gaugeData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  gaugeData.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
  gaugeData.addColumn('number', 'Humidity');
  gaugeData.addRows(2);
  gaugeData.setCell(0, 0, 120);
  gaugeData.setCell(0, 1, 80);

  gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div'));
  gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
  repeat();
}

function repeat() {
  var dir = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  gaugeData.setValue(0, 0, dir * 25);
  gaugeData.setValue(0, 1, dir * 20);
  gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
  setTimeout(repeat, 5000);
}
```

Repeat function is going to be executed every 5 seconds. In a sample fiddle it gets some random number from 1 to 10 and updates charts with this value multiplied by 25 and 20. In your scenario, you should make a call to your web server, parse the response, get values for temperature and humidity and update the charts. Please let me know if you need help on this too.

Comment: How would I retrieve temperature and humidity returned from MCU web server in repeat function ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to retreive temperature and humidity, you can do (using jquery):

```
function repeat() {
    $.get( "YOUR_WEB_SERVER_JSON_URL", function( data ) {
    gaugeData.setValue(0, 0, data.arduino[0].temperature);
    gaugeData.setValue(0, 1, data.arduino[1].humidity);
    gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
    setTimeout(repeat, 5000);
});
```

I've set up a simple example for you, check it out [here](http://dev.mobilestudio.pl/gauge.html).

Comment: After the json web URL what is the second parameter you are passing, unlike Python I don't understand how `function(data)`  returns.

Comment: It is not working : if you can get it to work just for temperature that would be enough : here is the json url: `https://data.sparkfun.com/output/dZ4EVmE8yGCRGx5XRX1W.json`

and share code with comments i can learn from

Comment: You need to follow those steps: 1. Create some server side code, which will get json content from https://data.sparkfun.com/output/dZ4EVmE8yGCRGx5XRX1W.json (which is quite large and it is not going to be lightning fast) and returns the latest temperature data in a form of json or some other data type. 2. Then you can call this server side function from your clientside script (using jQuery's $.get). Client code cannot connect to your json data directly - they are in different domains. Try to write something, I can help you with some issues.

Comment: The URL above is just an example, in my case the output json would always be what I have mentioned in the post above. So I don't think it's going to be heavy , I just need the value from the json sample given in opening post above to be set on gauge.

Comment: Is your json url a part of the same application as gauge page?

Comment: No man, it is not, that's why I need to get using Ajax or JavaScript XMLHttpResponse. If that was the case it might have been lot easier .

Comment: Do you have the exact url you wanna use? I could check and use some proxy to grab the data.

Comment: Not at the moment I left server at home running to be able to implement the web side while on vacation but it seems like router went offline as I am not able to access anything I self host.  But I assume the data retrieved from the URL I have already provided we need last item of the list . That needs to be `setCell(0,0, data.tempf)` . Thanks for helping out so much

Comment: I still think that you have to use some server side code proxy in order to grab the json data from other domain (data.sparkfun...) and expose it to ajax call from your page. Ping me with your url when you can - I will be able to help you on this.